# Why can we assign value in parentheses in Java?

Tags: java

I'm looking at Tomcat's Java source code and found code like this

```
String a = ("aa");
int b = (1);
```

It compiles successfully, while normally assignment should be

```
String a = "a";
int b = 1;
```

Why does first piece of code compile successfully?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: I suggest you add links to a couple examples in the Tomcat source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Syntactically, those aren't assignments: they are *variable declarations with initializers*. (This isn't that important a distinction in terms of the `()`, however).

The (simplified) form of a variable declaration with an initializer is:

```
Type name = expression;
```

Any expression of compatible type can appear on the right-hand side of the equals.

`()` makes a *parenthesized expression*. From [the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.5):

> A parenthesized expression is a primary expression whose type is the type of the contained expression and whose value at run time is the value of the contained expression.

So, it simply has the same value as what is in the brackets.

In this case, there is no reason whatsoever to use the `()`, but they don't change the meaning of the code.